# Clang enforce [[nodiscard]] by default?

Tags: c++, clang, nodiscard

C++17 has the `nodiscard` attribute to prevent people ignoring a function's return value.

It seems overkill to add this to every single function in a code base.

Is there a flag to tell Clang to enforce this by default?

Comment: It is discussed here: [What's the reason for not using C++17's \[\[nodiscard\]\] almost everywhere in new code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/363169/whats-the-reason-for-not-using-c17s-nodiscard-almost-everywhere-in-new-c)